# Weierstrauss Theorem for infinite products in Schaum's Complex Variables by Spiegel

Tags: complex-analysis

The following theorem is given in that book, but with no proof:

Let $f$ be entire with simple zeroes $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ where $0<|a_1| \leq |a_2| \leq \ldots$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = \infty$. Then $f$ can be expressed

$$
f(z) = f(0)e^{f'(0)z/f(0)} \prod_{k=1}^\infty \Big\{ (1-\frac{z}{a_k})e^{z/a_k}\Big\}
$$

I'm trying to understand the proof (actually the book says $|a_j| < |a_{j+1}|$ rather than $|a_j| \leq |a_{j+1}|$). I thought that perhaps this can be proved in the following way. If we look at $g=f'/f$, then $g$ has simple poles with residues 1 at each of the $a_k$'s. We might therefore be able to apply the Mittag-Leffler expansion theorem (Section 7.9 of that same book). This all works correctly and gives us what we want, but the problem is that the Mittag-Leffler theorem requires boundedness on circles whose radius goes to infinity, and I don't see that we have that in this case.

Does anyone see how this goes?
Thanks,
Greg

Comment: You need some condition on $a_k$ like $\sum |a_k|^{-2}$ finite for the product convvergence; this follows for example from order bounds, eg if $f$ entire exponential

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right. It seems that we need some conditions on the $a_k$'s for this to converge. I don't think the theorem is stated properly in the book. Thanks!